# PHP error reporting works ONLY when line is added in code

Tags: php, ini, error-reporting

I have a problem with my PHP error_reporting.
I have all the values for error_reporting and display_errors set in php.ini but my code still remains blank page until I add a line in php code :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Only after adding this line in my code I can see errors, such as

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\...\index.php on line 4
```

How do I change php.ini (or something else, perhaps?) to get the errors without adding this line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. using `phpinfo()` verify the actual `php.ini` location
2. restart web-server